# Actualizar el contenido de un div cada cierto tiempo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo este código que me actualiza el contenido de un div cada 5 segundos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(sensor,5000);
});

function sensor(){
$("#ex2").load("http://localhost:8050/ss2");
}
</script>
```

En si el contenido es una tabla que muestra los datos de una base de datos y esta se actualiza constantemente, la información se logra actualizar pero al momento que empiezan dichas actualizaciones me trae la pagina completa dentro del div de esta manera:

[image: Imagen de la tabla antes de actualizar]
**Imagen(1) de la tabla antes de actualizar**

[image: Imagen después de que se actualiza]
**Imagen(2) después de que se actualiza**

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este problema?

Saludos.

Comment: Investiga sobre API's

Answer (score 1):

```
http://localhost:8050/ss2
```

la pagina que cargas inicialmente crea toda la pagina incluyendo la tabla.

crea otra pagina que solamente devuelva la tabla.
    http://localhost:8050/alguna-direccion-de-tabla

```
<script>
function sensor(){
$("#ex2").load("http://localhost:8050/alguna-direccion-de-tabla");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], pues tu respuesta parece más un comentario; edita y amplia